# Mini-Max Sum - Wrong output

Tags: javascript, arrays, reduce, console.log

> Given five positive integers, find the minimum and maximum values that can be calculated by summing exactly four of the five integers. Then print the respective minimum and maximum values as a single line of two space-separated long integers.
>
> For example, if the array is [1, 3, 5, 7, 9]. Our minimum sum is 1 + 3 + 5 + 7 = 16 and our maximum sum is 3 + 5 + 7 + 9 = 24.

```
function miniMaxSum(arr) {
   let max = arr.reduce((a, b) => a + b, 1);

   let min = arr.reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0, arr.length - 1);

   console.log(min, max);
}
```

Right now, the output should be 10, 14 if the array is just [1, 2, 3, 4, 5].

The output I am getting is 15, 16.

The max variable should just add everything starting from index 1 no?

And the min variable I'm not sure if you're able to do this, but my thinking was initialize the starting at index 0 and go up to the end of the array but minus 1 index.

How can I correct this?

Comment: I think you're misunderstanding reduce.  That second param is the starting value of the accumulator, nothing to do with which array index you start or end at

Comment: Good point, didn't think of that edge case right now, just was wondering why it wasn't working with that particular array first

Comment: Seems like you could get the sum, subtract the max value from the sum to get the min, and then subtract the min value from the sum to get the max

Comment: @danh you are absolutely correct, i looked over reduce and see what's going on now, was confused by that whole 1st parameter thing

Comment: The first parameter of `reduce` is the callback. The second parameter, if provided, is the initial value of the accumulator. If there is no second parameter, the initial value of the accumulator is the first item in the array, and the callback is called starting at the second value in the array. Otherwise, the callback is called starting at the first value in the array (with an initial value / accumulator of the second parameter passed to `.reduce`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to identify which 4 of the 5 elements are the largest, and which 4 of the 5 elements are the smallest - or, equivalently, identify which *one* element is the smallest, and which *one* element is the largest, and subtract those from the sum of all 5 elements:

```js
function miniMaxSum(arr) {
  // fullSum: sum of all items in the array
  const fullSum = arr.reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0);
  // Find smallest value in array
  const min = Math.min(...arr);
  // Find largest value in array
  const max = Math.max(...arr);

  console.log(fullSum - max, fullSum - min);
}
miniMaxSum([1, 3, 5, 7, 9]);
miniMaxSum([1, 2, 3, 4, 5]);
```

Comment: Gotcha, appreciate that. but let's just say for the array of 1 through 5, why won't my code work for just that particular array?

Comment: Your logic just doesn't make any sense at all. `let max = arr.reduce((a, b) => a + b, 1);` will result in a sum of all items in the array, plus one. `let min = arr.reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0, arr.length - 1);` will result in a sum of all items in the array, plus the array's length, minus one. Neither of those has anything to do with identifying the 4 smallest / 4 largest (or one smallest, or one largest) value

Comment: yeah, just looked over reduce and confused a few things, that 2 param is just an initial value if you want to specify. I mixed that up with index.

Comment: Even if you used the index, that would only work if the arrays are guaranteed to be sorted first, which isn't stated in the question, so it shouldn't be assumed. (even if you were to sort it yourself, that would have `O(n log n)` complexity, so it's not an elegant idea, especially given how simple the other solution is)

Comment: that's true, didn't think about if it was sorted, appreciate the response

Comment: Generalizing the problem just a little to "find the min and max given by summing a subset of length A in a set of length B (where A<B)" , the sort starts to look like a pretty good deal.

Answer (score 1):

Another approach is to use slice and sum the small and and the large end of the array.

```js
function miniMax(arr) {
  const sum = a => a.reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0);

  // we can skip the sort if we know the input is sorted, but just in case
  const sorted = arr.sort((a,b) => a-b)
  
  const min = sum(sorted.slice(0, sorted.length-1))  // sum the small end of the array
  const max = sum(sorted.slice(1))  // sum the large end of the array

  return { min, max }
}

console.log(miniMax([1, 3, 5, 7, 9]));
console.log(miniMax([1, 2, 3, 4, 5]));
```

Answer (score 1):

**This only works if the numbers are listed in ascending order in the array**

```js
function miniMaxSum(arr)
  {
  let max = arr.reduce((a,c,i)=>i?a+c:0, 0);
  let min = arr.reduce((a,c,i,t)=>i?a+t[i-1]:0, 0);
  document.write(`${JSON.stringify(arr)} -> min: ${min}, max: ${max} <br>`);
}

miniMaxSum([1, 3, 5, 7, 9]);

miniMaxSum([1, 2, 3, 4, 5]);
```

It was fun to do ;)

Comment: nice solution, appreciate the response